# How to convert Un-allocated space to free space in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning, dualboot

I have two disk.

```
disk 0 (Hdd 1Tb)
disk 1  (Ssd 240 Gb)
```

I am making dual boot by installing ubuntu. I followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/343370/1391635) normal guide of dual booting.

I created un-allocated space of 60 GB in disk 1 for ubuntu.

But in process of installing It should have free space but it shows that un-allocated space as unusable so I am not able to partition it.

So how should I make that un-allocated partition free ?

**My disk space**

[image: My disk space]

**Problem while installing ubuntu Unusable partition**

[image: Problem while installing ubuntu Unusable partition]

Answer (score 2):

In Windows terms, "Unallocated" space *is* what you want. That's just space where no partitions have been created yet. (Other programs like GParted might call the *same* thing "free" space, but it's still just space that has no partitions.)

The problem is, it looks like both disks use the MBR partition table – it has a limit of 4 partitions total. In your Disk 0, an "extended" partition was created to get around this limit (the green border around E: and F: indicates an extended partition which holds two "logical" partitions), but in Disk 1 this wasn't done – all four partitions in there have been created as "primary", i.e. directly using the MBR's 4 slots.

Because all 4 partition slots are in use, this means that the unallocated space on Disk 1 can only be used for growing an existing partition (making C: larger) but not for creating new partitions.

What you can do is:

- Preferred option: Check whether your system has UEFI firmware, so that you could use the Windows `mbr2gpt` tool to convert Disk 1 to GPT partitioning. Doing so would allow you to create a practically unlimited number of partitions in Disk 1, without worrying about "extended" or "logical" partitions. Another advantage of UEFI boot (over BIOS/CSM/legacy boot) is that the Windows bootloader is not overwritten by installing Ubuntu – the firmware itself will let you choose whether to boot via Ubuntu's GRUB or via Windows Boot Manager.
- Second option: Delete those "Recovery partitions". You have two of them, and only one is current (most likely the larger one), the other is just wasting space. You could use GParted to delete the smaller partition, move the larger one to the right, and the MBR would have 1 free slot for Ubuntu (which could be used to create an "extended" partition if necessary).

(If those were purely data partitions, you could use the Linux `fdisk` to carefully delete them and re-create as logical partitions, keeping the exact same start/end would preserve the data. But the Windows "recovery" partitions wouldn't remain bootable after doing so.)

Comment: first of all thanks. I have  legacy bios. So I think I have only second option you suggested. By the way for your information I don't know in detail any of this. I just follow one youtube video & I stuck here. can you little bit elaborate 2nd option or give link where it detailed explained. Also by the way if I choose option `install ubuntu alongside windows boot manager` rather than `something else` is it fine ?

Comment: First disk with the exended partition can't be converted to GPT with MBR2GPT.

Comment: @Ramhound can you suggest what should I do and how should I do that ?

Comment: @user1686 please do reply

Comment: @AbhishekMane - Delete the extended partition.

Comment: @Ramhound Really thanks. Now I have free space on `disk 0(hdd)` but if possible I want to install ubuntu on my `disk 1(ssd)`  can you suggest what should I do ?

Comment: Your other disk is still not compatible with MBR2GPT.  You would have to delete one of your partitions to make it compatible. Based on your question, best to just perform a clean install, but only do that after the appropriate backup

Comment: @Ramhound: I wasn't talking about converting disk 0. There is no need to convert disk 0. It's a data disk, not a boot disk nor system disk, and its partition type is irrelevant.

Comment: @user1686 - I am aware of that. The author specifically ask how they could convert it.  So I answered the question. Dealing with a good old fashioned head cold so I replied with the most basic information possible

Comment: @Ramhound can you specifically mention disk & which volume because other disk means I am not getting about which you are talking. By following your last instructions this https://postimg.cc/zLTvPwgG is how my disk space look like.

Comment: You still have an extended partition on that disk. Your other disk has two many partitions to be converted.  As I have said, just format the disk, and reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound: Why are you telling OP to convert the other disk? They're trying to create the partitions on disk 1, not on disk 0. They don't need to convert disk 0, extended or not.

Comment: @user1686 - They could convert the other disk and install Windows on that disk, if they wanted, and it would boot in UEFI mode.  Both disks don't meet the requirements to be converted using MBR2GPT.

Comment: @Ramhound I don't want to format whole disk as then I have to copy data then install all applications and again paste data it's lot headache. is there any other option ? By the way I deleted right most recovery partition and moved only remained recovery partition to right side. Now my disk space look like this https://postimg.cc/f3LMwysQ  Now what should I do ?

Comment: @user1686 check my last comment now I am able do exactly what you told me as second option. please guide me further what should I do now ?

Comment: You have to convert the drive with the unallocated partition, to GPT, in order to achieve what you want. In order to achieve that, it must have 3 partitions and meet the requirements for MBR2GPT to function. The simplest method is to start completely over. The requirements for MBR2GPT are well documented and I grow tired of this unnecessary discussion within the comment section. I will be unable to guide you with your question in its current state

Comment: @Ramhound finally I am able to do it. I just organize disk 1 by deleting and creating partition to make free space.